# Avoiding 2nd semantic-release Commit on Bitbucket Cloud

Tags: bitbucket-cloud, semantic-release

I'm using Bitbucket Cloud and everything works wonderfully using pipelines, except I always get an extra commit after my release/tag commit, as follows:

`Notes added by 'git notes add'` -- author: `semantic-release-bot`

Is there any way to avoid this?

Here's my config:

```
    "release": {
        "plugins": [
            "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
            [
                "@semantic-release/changelog",
                {
                    "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
                }
            ],
            [
                "@semantic-release/npm",
                {
                    "npmPublish": false
                }
            ],
            [
                "@semantic-release/git",
                {
                    "assets": ["CHANGELOG.md"]
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

@Sammy - Have you tried to set the message for the commit? Bitbucket recommends using [skip ci] in pipelines

```json
      {
        "path": "@semantic-release/git",
        "message": "chore(release): ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
      }
```

Comment: Thanks but it turned out to simply be Bitbucket’s interpretation of Git Notes that’s lacking, and so makes them appear as extra commits.